# In AVL-Tree, why needs more one performance of rotation in deletion?

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

let z be the first unbalanced node.

in deletion, after we perform a rotation at z, we may have to perform a rotation at ancestors of z. Thus, we must continue to trace the path until we reach the root.http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-2-deletion/

but why ancestors of z may needs rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the subtree may have become shorter which may violate the AVL condition at any level. Take this example

```
              5
      2               8
   1     3         7     10
           4      6    9    11
                              12
```

After you delete 1, a rotation at 2 is necessary and also at 5.

Comment: no, your example is wrong! because 5 is unbalance, so before you erase 1, you must rotate 5.

Comment: @Limer No, the tree is perfectly OK. The right subtree of 5 is just 1 higher than the left.